# In the Bibliography, how to display the pages where the citations appear?

Tags: bibliographies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bibliography with page numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15971/bibliography-with-page-numbers)

I'd like to display after each bibliography item the numbers of the pages [or maybe the sections] where it is cited.

I use LaTeX thebibliography enviroment (not BibTex).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice question :). I found this topic which is exactly the same on TeX.SE: 
[Bibliography with page numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15971/bibliography-with-page-numbers).