# Indexing the page number of each bibliography item

Tags: bibliographies, indexing

Assume that that I am using the following environment for the references of my paper:

```
\bibliographystyle {amsalpha}
\begin {thebibliography} {VDN92}
\bibitem{abels} {\bf H. Abels,} Parallelizability ... Math. Ann. vol. 212, (1974), 1--19.

\end {thebibliography}
```

What should I do to add the page number of occurrences of this paper (those pages of my paper that I have cited the above paper) at the end of this citation?

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but, in case you don't already know, biblatex can do this with the 'backref' option.

Comment: You can also take a look at [Bibliography with page numbers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15971/27635)

Comment: @karlkoeller: Thank you very much for the link! It works perfectly. :))