# Which package should I use?

Tags: ref

I am reading a pdf which I guess it's written in LaTex, so all I need to know is that which package is this to refer figures and bib items?

[image]

[image]

Comment: try with `hyperref.sty`

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking, which package adds the highlighted links, this is probably `hyperref`. To create links, back to where you are linking, this can be achieved through the `backref` option: https://mirror.kumi.systems/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.html#x1-450005.26

An example can be found at [Bibliography with page numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15971/bibliography-with-page-numbers)

Comment: I am using hyperref but how can I add used pages after bib items which I mentioned with red circles?