# How to add cite page occurrence for reference

Tags: bibtex

I'm using BibTex to cite. If I cite an article on pages 4 and 5, how can I make the reference look like the following result (the red 4,5):

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Does the posting [Bibliography with page numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15971/5001) address your query?

Comment: @Mico Thank you so much, I'm a beginner, so I have some questions that may not be searched in the right way, thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Now I understand that the characteristic I need is called "back reference", more precisely is "page back reference".

So I changed config of package `hyperref` from

```latex
\usepackage[breaklinks=true,bookmarks=false]{hyperref}
```

to

```latex
\usepackage[breaklinks=true,bookmarks=false,pagebackref]{hyperref}
```

This solved my question.